# Xcode terminates my image generating app after a while

Tags: ios, uiimage, core-graphics

I am trying to generate 60,000 images using this code

```
-(void)createImages
{
    [self.actIndicator startAnimating];
    for(int i = 0; i < kImgCount; i++) {
        CGSize imageSize = CGSizeMake(50, 50);
        UIColor *fillColor = [self randomColor];
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imageSize, YES, 0);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        [fillColor setFill];
        CGContextFillRect(context, CGRectMake(0, 0, imageSize.width,  imageSize.height));
        UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
        self.imagesCreated++;
        NSLog(@"%ld", (long)self.imagesCreated);
    }
    [self.actIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Here kImgCount is equal to 60,000. Xcode loses connection to the app after a while which gets terminated. Lowering kImgCount to 14000, however runs fine. Also, the completion selector @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:) never gets called. I tried placing a breakpoint in didRecieveMemoryWarning, but this is never called. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I saw in the last few iterations that image writing was failing, with an error description of "Busy write". So, I am now writing the images such that the call to UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum for writing the next image happens only when my completion selector gets called saying that the image has been written. So far, I have been able to save some 17000 images to the camera roll, in about 90 minutes. But, this is slow? Is there any way I could speed it up? Can I write images in parallel?